# How this query be optimised to prevent timeout

Tags: mysql, sql

From the database below with schema

```
movieActor (actorID, movieID)
rental (rentalID, inventoryID, customerID)
inventory (inventoryID, movieID)
```

I am trying to list pair of customers who rented movies from same actor. The resulting set should be composed of three columns

```
customerID1,customerID2,nOfCommonActors
```

for example

```
23 44 5 
11 44 3
```

where the first row means customers with ids of 23 and 44 each rented various movies but 5 of those actors played in both set of movies customer 23 and 44 rented

I came up with this query however it takes so much time to run and times out without returning any result. Was wondering how I can make it more efficient( I am using MYSQL):

```
SELECT r1.customerID AS customerID1,
    r2.customerID AS customerID2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fa.actorID) as nOfCommonActors
FROM movieActor AS fa
    JOIN (SELECT r.customerID, i.movieID, fa.actorID
    FROM rental AS r
        JOIN inventory i
        ON i.inventoryID=r.inventoryID
        JOIN movieActor AS fa
        ON fa.actorID=i.movieID
) AS r1
    JOIN (SELECT r.customerID, i.movieID, fa.actorID
    FROM rental AS r
        JOIN inventory i
        ON i.inventoryID=r.inventoryID
        JOIN movieActor AS fa
        ON fa.actorID=i.movieID
) AS r2
    ON r2.actorID=r1.actorID
        AND r1.customerID < r2.customerID 
GROUP BY r1.customerID, r2.customerID
ORDER BY nOfCommonActors DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I can think of is `select distinct` in the subqueries:

```
SELECT ca.customerID AS customerID1,
       ca2.customerID AS customerID2,
       COUNT(*) as nOfCommonActors
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.customerID, fa.actorID
      FROM rental r JOIN
           inventory i
           ON i.inventoryID = r.inventoryID JOIN
           movieActor fa
           ON fa.actorID = i.movieID
     ) ca JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT r.customerID, fa.actorID
      FROM rental r JOIN
           inventory i
           ON i.inventoryID = r.inventoryID JOIN
           movieActor fa
           ON fa.actorID = i.movieID
    ) ca2
    ON ca.actorID = ca2.actorID AND
        ca.customerID < ca2.customerID
GROUP BY ca.customerID, ca2.customerID
ORDER BY nOfCommonActors DESC;
```

Your version is multiplying out the number of rows in the subqueries considerably.  That makes the `JOIN` more expensive -- and all that extra work is for nought because you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the query into, allows allows statistic to plot best path

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.customerID, fa.actorID
into #t1
      FROM rental r JOIN
           inventory i
           ON i.inventoryID = r.inventoryID JOIN
           movieActor fa
           ON fa.actorID = i.movieID


SELECT DISTINCT r.customerID, fa.actorID
into #t1
      FROM rental r JOIN
           inventory i
           ON i.inventoryID = r.inventoryID JOIN
           movieActor fa
           ON fa.actorID = i.movieID

select #t1.customerID AS customerID1,
       #t2.customerID AS customerID2,
       COUNT(*) as nOfCommonActors
from 
        (
        select #t1.customerID, #t2.customerID
        from #t1
        join #t2 ON #t1.actorID = #t2.actorID AND #t1.customerID < #t2.customerID )

GROUP BY #t1.customerID, #t2.customerID
ORDER BY nOfCommonActors DESC;
```